# How do I configure Response Headers that apply to the content delivery system not Sitecore?

Tags: response-headers

We are in the process of launching a new site hosted in Azure. We have been running Tenable Scans on the site.

The report keeps indicating that the response header is missing X-Content-Type-Options and some Content-Security-Policy settings in the Web.config.

Seems like an easy thing to fix, except it appears those settings are already in place; however, I missed the fact that they are under the node of `<location path=sitecore>`as shown below.

My colleague said we need to set these polices outside of the node `<location path=sitecore>`, but I am not exactly certain where these need to go, and we don't want to remove the node `<location path=sitecore>`.

I had the same problem with X-Frame Options and I set up this xdt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" xdt:Transform="Insert"/>
                <add name="Content-Security-Policy"
                      value="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://apps.sitecore.net; img-src 'self' data:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com; font-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.gstatic.com; upgrade-insecure-requests; block-all-mixed-content; 
                      frame-ancestors 'self';" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Note: I did not include the `<location path=sitecore>` in the above and the problem was resolved, so do I just set up a similar xdt?

```
<location path="sitecore">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <remove name="X-Content-Type-Options" />
          <remove name="X-XSS-Protection" />
          <remove name="Content-Security-Policy" />
          <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block" />
          <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff " />
          <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src 'self' data:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com; font-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.gstatic.com; upgrade-insecure-requests; block-all-mixed-content;" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Comment: Are you using SXA or traditional MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understanding XDT can be a bit difficult at first. To explain how the transformation works, let's go through the XML, step-by-step.

1. XDT looks for `configuration` element in the XML to modify.
2. It then looks for a `system.webServer` element.
3. It then looks for an `httpProtocol` element.
4. It then finds `customHeaders` element.
5. It then looks for an `add` element (you probably have multiple of these).
   It then finds add element's which `key` attribute equals `Content-Security-Policy`.
6. Finally, it updates the value of `Content-Security-Policy` with provided value.

If you look into the current web.config file, you will notice 2  XML nodes.

[image]

For CD do apply outside of the node `<location path=sitecore>` and it will work fine. You can go with the first `xdt` example file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" xdt:Transform="Insert"/>
                <add name="Content-Security-Policy"
                      value="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://apps.sitecore.net; img-src 'self' data:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com; font-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.gstatic.com; upgrade-insecure-requests; block-all-mixed-content; 
                      frame-ancestors 'self';" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, I think you confirmed what I thought. thank you very much for taking the time.

Comment: I'm glad it helps, If this answer or any other one solved your issue or helps to resolve it, please mark it as accepted for the community. For more details https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers